# How to create "wave"-like type in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, 3d, creative-cloud

I managed to create a text following a wave pattern in After Effects using the CC Cylinder effect but I can't find how to replicate it in Illustrator. I tried the Map Art effect under the Extrude and Bevel effects but I don't know how to make the text repeat like in this still of the animation.
Does somebody know how to recreate this effect in Illustrator ?
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: related https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67957/how-to-produce-a-ripple-effect-like-this/76213

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make a path with a **Zig Zag** effect

[image: zig zag]

Extrude this path. Apply a Perspective number to make a distortion:

[image: Extrude]

Make a **Symbol** with the text and edit the **Extrude & Bevel Options** from the **Appearance Panel** to apply it as a **Map Art**

- Click the **Map Art** button
- Choose the face surface at the top right options
- Select the the text symbol
- Scale it and rotate it if necessary
- Check **Invisible Geometry**

[image: Map Art]

Duplicate the original extruded path, stroke it with white color and edit the Extrude & Bevel Options from the Appearance Panel to define the light settings:

[image: shadows]

Place it on top aligned with the extruded Map Art shape and change the Blend Mode to Multiply

[image]